# Inject CSS using a textarea?

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to inject/append CSS pasted into a textarea into the head section of the page? I'm making the settings page for an app, and I want to allow themes and the option to change minor things by just adding CSS into a textarea then clicking save.

Other option: Is it posiible to have the textarea display a file called "theme.css" then any changes made will be saved as that file. And to completely change the theme, just copy/paste a new one directly into the text box.

Comment: You could sanitize and then store the CSS in a database. When you need to display the custom CSS, you could either just output it in between `<style>` tags or have a `user_style.php` file read the CSS from your database.

Comment: To show a block of editable CSS, you could just give it the `contenteditable` HTML5 property, and use the following CSS to make it show up on your HTML page: `style.editable{display:block;}`. This, of course, would always be local, and wouldn't save it to the server, so you'd need some Javascript, PHP, or another language to communicate with the server side to make this change permanent. Reference: http://css-tricks.com/show-and-edit-style-element/

Answer (score 3):

If you use jquery this is how you can do

```
<script>
$("head").append("<style>body {background:blue;}</style>");
</script>
```

As another option

you can read theme.css file using `fread` , show it in textarea and save it to file using `fwrite`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function addStyle(css){
        var stl = document.createElement('style');
        stl.innerHTML = css;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stl);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Paragraph To Test<p>
<textarea id="txtarea">p{color:red;}</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Set Style" onclick="addStyle(txtarea.value);">
</body>
</html>
```